# how to setCookie in gwt client?

Tags: gwt, openid, smartgwt, gwt-rpc

in my servlet, i have this line

CookieManager.getRequestCookieValue(request, "app-openid-identifier");
CookieManager.getRequestCookieValue(request, "app-openid-uniqueid");

in my gwt client composite file, how to i set cookie for "app-openid-identifier" and do "get" to call the servlet?

Answer (score 6):

In your GWT application you can use:

```
com.google.gwt.user.client.Cookies.setCookie("app-openid-identifier","some value");
```

For a GET request use:

```
com.google.gwt.http.client.RequestBuilder
```

Or if possible try to use RPC calls instead.